# zone.run() on Observable.bindCallback()

Tags: angular, rxjs, electron, angular2-observables, zone.js

I am using Electron, and as you may know, all of Electron's calls run outside of Angular's `zone`. So you need to call `zone.run()` at some point when using Electron methods.

A typical Electron call looks like this (Notice the `zone.run()`):

```
    this.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {
            properties: ['openDirectory'],
        },
        (directories) => {
            const projectName = path.basename(directories[0]);

            this.zone.run(() => {
                cb(projectName);
            });
        },
    );
```

The above works **perfectly fine**. I am a happy man. I could walk away right now, and accept this. However, I would like to write this with `Observables`, so it connects well with other aspects of the App.

```
    const openDialog = Observable.bindCallback(this.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog);
    return openDialog({
        properties: ['openDirectory'],
    }).map((directories) => {
        const projectName = path.basename(directories[0]);
        // WHERE DO I PUT ZONE.RUN?
        return projectName;
    });
```

Where do I put `zone.run`?

Answer (score 1):

zone.js have documentation for covering both rxjs / electron api patching: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md#usage

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the "run" hint inside of the completion of the subscription:

```
}).map((directories) => {
        const projectName = path.basename(directories[0]);
        this.zone.run();  // <---- Right here?
        return projectName;
    });
```

Comment: Because thats invalid syntax. You need to do `this.zone(() => {
   // INSIDE ZONE NOW
})`

Answer (score 0):

All electron API are patched, you need to put this line in `polyfill.ts` after loading `zone.js`.

```
//import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // originally added by angular-cli, comment it out
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-mix'; // add zone-mix to patch both Browser and Nodejs
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-electron'; // add zone-patch-electron to patch Electron native API
```

And I also created a sample repo https://github.com/JiaLiPassion/zone-electron